# Complex Clustering of Rows in Large Table - SQL in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, cluster-analysis

I try to find common clusters in a large table. I have my data in Google BigQuery.
My data consists of many transactions `tx` from different user groups. User groups can have multiple `id`s and I try to cluster all ids to the respective user group by analyzing their transactions.

I identified four rules that identify ids from the same user group. In the brackets I named this cluster rule so that you can map the rule to the SQL below:

- all ids that belong to the same `tx` where `is_type_0 = TRUE` belong to the same user group (="cluster_is_type_0")
- all ids that belong to the same `tx` where `is_type_1 = FALSE` belong to the same user group (="cluster_is_type_1")
- all ids that belong to the same `tx` where `is_type_1 = TRUE` that did not exist in the row numbers before (`row_nr`), belong to the same user group (="cluster_id_occurence")
- all ids with the same `id` belong to the same user group (="cluster_id")

Here is some example data:

| row_nr | tx | id | is_type_1 | is_type_0 | expected_cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | z0 | a1 | true | true | 1 |
| 2 | z1 | b1 | true | true | 2 |
| 3 | z1 | b2 | true | true | 2 |
| 4 | z2 | c1 | true | true | 3 |
| 5 | z2 | c2 | true | true | 3 |
| 6 | z3 | d1 | true | true | 4 |
| 7 | z | a1 | false | false | 1 |
| 8 | z | b1 | true | false | 2 |
| 9 | z | a2 | true | false | 1 |
| 10 | y | b1 | false | false | 2 |
| 11 | y | b2 | false | false | 2 |
| 12 | y | a2 | true | false | 1 |
| 13 | x | c1 | false | false | 3 |
| 14 | x | c2 | false | false | 3 |
| 15 | x | b1 | true | false | 2 |
| 16 | x | c3 | true | false | 3 |
| 17 | w | a2 | false | false | 1 |
| 18 | w | c1 | true | false | 3 |
| 19 | w | a3 | true | false | 1 |
| 20 | v | b1 | false | false | 2 |
| 21 | v | b2 | false | false | 2 |
| 22 | v | a2 | true | false | 1 |

This is what I already tried:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT
    (1 as row_nr, 'z0' as tx, 'a1' as id, TRUE as is_type_1, TRUE as is_type_0, 1 as expected_cluster), 
    (2,     'z1',   'b1',   TRUE,   TRUE,   2),
    (3,     'z1',   'b2',   TRUE,   TRUE,   2),
    (4,     'z2',   'c1',   TRUE,   TRUE,   3),
    (5,     'z2',   'c2',   TRUE,   TRUE,   3),
    (6,     'z3',   'd1',   TRUE,   TRUE,   4),
    (7,     'z',    'a1',   FALSE,  FALSE,  1),
    (8,     'z',    'b1',   TRUE,   FALSE,  2),
    (9,     'z',    'a2',   TRUE,   FALSE,  1),
    (10,     'y',    'b1',   FALSE,  FALSE,  2),
    (11,     'y',    'b2',   FALSE,  FALSE,  2),
    (12,     'y',    'a2',   TRUE,   FALSE,  1),
    (13,     'x',    'c1',   FALSE,  FALSE,  3),
    (14,    'x',    'c2',   FALSE,  FALSE,  3),
    (15,    'x',    'b1',   TRUE,   FALSE,  2),
    (16,    'x',    'c3',   TRUE,   FALSE,  3),
    (17,    'w',    'a2',   FALSE,  FALSE,  1),
    (18,    'w',    'c1',   TRUE,   FALSE,  3),
    (19,    'w',    'a3',   TRUE,   FALSE,  1),
    (20,    'v',    'b1',   FALSE,  FALSE,  2),
    (21,    'v',    'b2',   FALSE,  FALSE,  2),
    (22,    'v',    'a2',   TRUE,   FALSE,  1)
  ])
)
, first_cluster as (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY row_nr) as id_occurence
        , CASE WHEN NOT is_type_1 THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tx) END AS cluster_is_type_1
        , CASE WHEN is_type_0 THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tx) END AS cluster_is_type_0
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS cluster_id
    FROM data
    ORDER BY row_nr
)
, second_cluster AS (
    SELECT *
    ,   CASE WHEN id_occurence = 1 THEN MIN(cluster_is_type_1) OVER (PARTITION BY tx) END AS cluster_id_occurence
    FROM first_cluster
    ORDER BY row_nr
)
, third_cluster AS (
    SELECT *
        ,   COALESCE(cluster_is_type_1, cluster_id_occurence, cluster_is_type_0, cluster_id) AS combined_cluster
    FROM second_cluster
    ORDER BY row_nr
)

SELECT *
    -- ,   ARRAY_AGG(combined_cluster) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS combined_cluster_agg
    ,   MIN(combined_cluster) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS result_cluster
FROM third_cluster
ORDER BY id
```

But the result is not as expected. `id` `a1`, `a2` and `a3` are not considered to be the same cluster, and also `COALESCE(cluster_is_type_1, cluster_id_occurence, cluster_is_type_0, cluster_id) AS combined_cluster` can lead to some unwanted behavior as the defined clusters always start at 1 with the dense_rank and when you combine them like so it might be that `id`s end up in the same cluster that do not belong together.

I appreciate every help!

Comment: and how does it help?

Comment: Sorry for my last comment. The sample data shows following: User a1 is buying `tx` in z and z0. User b1 is buying `tx` in z and z1 and many more. You say these all fall in the same user group. Let's assume there is another user A, who bought only an item in z and another user B, who bought only an item in z1. Are these both users are in the same user group? If yes, then the first step would be to find all entries in `tx`, which are connected by an user interaction. Then replace these values in the `tx` column by a single one of them.

Comment: For the regrouping of `tx` by user buying/linking. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74157658/create-a-group-of-linked-items/74157659   An example of disjoint-set union (DSU)

Comment: Thanks, Samuel, sorry for the late response. I tried your solution and it works perfectly on a small subsample of my data, great! Sorry, here comes a noob question: I have never worked with `#recursive` before: If I want to store the results in a CTE and continue with plain SQL from there on, do I have to say `stop #recursive` somehow?

Comment: Also, unfortunately, with a dataset that is a bit bigger I gat an `Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 106% of limit.` error ):

Comment: The `recursive` after the  `with` indicates that there is at least one recursive CTE.  Non recursive CTE can be present as well. There is no need to stop recursive. Memory Peak usage can be solved sometimes by saving the tables temporary (or as regular tables in a dataset) instead of using CTEs.

Comment: Thanks, Samuel, for the explanation. I think the Memory Peak might occur because the array with `array_agg` sometimes gets huge. Do you think that can be solved with temporary tables?

Comment: The implementation of the DSU does not scale for large datasets. Could you please provided your total rows and count unique `tx` and unique `id` entries.

Comment: hm, I'm afraid I have quite a large dataset: total rows is ~ 5 billion, unique `id` is ~ 100 million and unique `tx` is almost 1 billion.

Comment: That is a huge amount of data. I guess that will be to much for a DSU algo in an UDF in BigQuery. Please try `select distinct a, b
from ( 
Select tx,min(id) as b, array_agg(id) as a_list
from data
group by 1
), unnest(a_list) as a` and tell me the anount of rows of that. For the UDF replace the `tx` by a numeric column; first extract tx `Select tx,row_number() over () as tx_int
 from data
 group by 1`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the super late answer. I tried the replacement of tx by the unique row_number but still get the Resources exceeded error. Regarding the row number: I only extracted the first 5 GB of 500 GB (quite expensive to do such tests otherwise :D ) - I have already 17590050 rows