# create a group of linked items

Tags: google-bigquery, union

There is a list of users, who buy different product items. I want to group the item by user buying behavior. If any user buys two products, these shall be in the same group. The buying links the products.

| user | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cat food |
| 1 | cat toy |
| 2 | cat toy |
| 2 | cat snacks |
| 10 | dog food |
| 10 | dog collar |
| 11 | dog food |
| 11 | candy |
| 12 | candy |
| 12 | apples |
| 15 | paper |

In this sample case all items for a cat shall be grouped together: "cat food" to "cat toy" to "cat snacks". The items with dog, candy, apples should be one group, because user buying’s link these. The paper is another group.

There are about 200 different products in the table and I need to do a disjoint-set union (DSU).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript there several implementation of Disjoint Set Union (DSU), here [this](https://gist.github.com/KSoto/3300322fc2fb9b270dce2bf1e3d80cf3) was used for the user defined function (UDF) in BigQuery. The main idea is to use a find and union function and to save the linking in a tree, represented as an array, please [see here for details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

```sql
create temp function DSU(A array<struct<a string,b string>>)
returns array<struct<a string,b string>>
language js as
"""
// https://gist.github.com/KSoto/3300322fc2fb9b270dce2bf1e3d80cf3
// Disjoint-set bigquery
class DSU {
  constructor() {
    this.parents = [];
  }

  find(x) {
    if(typeof this.parents[x] != "undefined") {
      if(this.parents[x]<0) {
        return x; 
      } else {
        if(this.parents[x]!=x) {
          this.parents[x]=this.find(this.parents[x]);
      }
        return (this.parents[x]);
      }
    } else {
      this.parents[x]=-1;
      return x; 
    }

  }

  union(x,y) {
    var xpar = this.find(x);
    var ypar = this.find(y);
    if(xpar != ypar) {
      this.parents[xpar]+=this.parents[ypar]; 
      this.parents[ypar]=xpar;  
    } 
  }

 console_print() {
//    console.log(this.parents);
  }

}

var dsu = new DSU();
for(var i in A){
  dsu.union(A[i].a,A[i].b);
}

var out=[]
for(var i in A){
  out[i]={b:dsu.find(A[i].a),a:A[i].a};
}
return out;
""";

with #recursive

your_table as (
    SELECT 1 as user, "cat food" as item
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, "cat toy"
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, "cat snacks"
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, "cat toy"
    UNION ALL SELECT 10, "dog food"
    union all select 10, "dog collar"
    union all select 11, "dog food"
    union all select 11, "candy"
    union all select 12, "candy"
    union all select 12, "apples"
    union all select 15, "paper"
), helper as (
select distinct a, b
from ( 
Select user,min(item) as b, array_agg(item) as a_list
from your_table
group by 1
), unnest(a_list) as a
)

Select * except(tmp_count),
first_value(item) over(partition by b order by tmp_count desc,b) as item_most_common
from
(
select * ,
count(item) over(partition by b,item) as tmp_count
from your_table
left join (select  X.a, min(X.b) as b from (select DSU(array_agg(struct(''||a,''||b))) as X from helper),unnest(X) X group by 1 order by 1) as  combinder
on ''||item=combinder.a
)
```

The data is in the table `your_table`. A `helper` table is used to buid all pairs of two items, which any user brought. Combined as an array, this is giving to the UDF `DSU`. This function returns all items in column `a` and in column `b` the group. We want the most common item of the group to be shown as group name, therefore we use some window functions to determine it.